# git-svn: merging two svn branches - add/add conflicts with no local changes

Tags: git, version-control, git-svn, git-merge

I have my repository setup with git-svn and two branches with an svn remote.
I want to merge changes from svn-trunk into the svn-branch1 and then propagate those to my local git only branches.

I am using:

```
git checkout branch1
git merge master
```

The merge always results in add/add conflicts for every file edited in trunk, even when branch1 does not have any local changes. Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

How do you suggest propagating the changes to the git branches? I am using:

```
git checkout branch1_gitlocal
git rebase branch1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to the add/add conflicts, this happens because the repository in question was non-standard and therefore git was not recognizing a branch as a branch.
To solve this, the git repository must be initialized with the information of the actual structure of the svn original repository.
See the [reference](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) for the list of options.

As to the "correct way" of propagating the changes to the git branches, I have no new suggestions.